# difference between semicolon and double ampersand in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a question about makefile (not talking about Linux shell or bash here). What is the difference between semicolon and double ampersand in a make file?

On the first computer, the following works:

```
cd code; ant clean compile jar run
```

On the second computer, the above doesn't work while the below works:

```
cd code && ant clean compile jar run
```

The above code is inside the file called "makefile". I want to know the difference between '&&' and ';'.

Thanks

Note:
My error message for semicolon on second computer is

```
cd code; ant clean compile jar run
The system cannot find the path specified.
make: *** [runant] Error 1
```

Comment: On the first computer, both version works.

Comment: Those two commands are shell commands which Make passes to the shell; Make doesn't parse them, doesn't interpret them, and doesn't care what the shell does with them.

Comment: Thanks for the information, do you have an idea about why semicolon only work on one computer?

Comment: My error message is "cd code; ant clean compile jar run\n" "The system cannot find the path specified.\n" "make: *** [runant] Error 1\n" for the semicolon on second computer

Comment: I will modify my question post to show this info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

see https://serverfault.com/a/373053/85018 for a good explanation:

> The ; just separates one command from another. The && says only run the following command if the previous was successful

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have the "code" folder in both of my terminal/cmd directory, so both && and ; should work. However, semicolon only work on first computer, do you have an idea about the reason behind this?

Comment: The error message suggests you are on Windows. Several Google results say that semicolon does not work with cmd

Comment: I see, that solves my question, thank you for your time.